# Regex for mysql query to match html entities

Tags: mysql, regex, posix

I understand PCRE pretty well, but MySQL's regular expression flavor seems to get the best of me.

Can someone help me correct this expression? The PCRE equivalent would be `&\w+;`

I'm guessing something like:

`select body from email where body rlike '&[[:alpha:]]+;%'`

### Bonus:

[MySQL's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) on their regex flavor seem kinda sparse. Does anyone have a good resource specifically geared toward mysql regex they can point me to?

Comment: A bonus question... funny :) Is there also a bonus award? ;)

Comment: @Felix: yes, the OP will get friends to join SO and upvote too.

Comment: Bonus cheat: http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select body from email where body REGEXP '\&[a-z0-9A-Z]+\;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_MySQL_Regular_Expressions.htm